# Window-manager buttons no longer highlight on mouseover if window isn't maximized

Tags: 11.10, window

Since the upgrade to 11.10, the window buttons (close, minimize, maximize) only highlight on mouseover when the window is maximized, as shown in the images below:

Not maximized - no highlighting: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSVdO.png]

Maximized - highlighting: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX6yS.png]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a full new install of 11.10 and know it works. The experienced behaviour may depend on the dist-upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same behavior, so I don't believe there is a "fix" as much as that this is the default behavior. If you believe it to be a problem, you should file a bug in launchpad against [Unity](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity).

Comment: It's not the default behavior, it happened to me on 11.04 as well but only on my desktop with an ATI Radeon HD 4xxx. My other pc with NVIDIA works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This does not depend on the dist-upgrade but in ATI drivers fglrx, while with the open driver everything works as expected (but with poor performances with Unity [gnome-shell is simply unusable with this driver])